# How to use query where using CASE in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to run this query, but the in the where statement the Case is giving an error. What I am trying to do is, if `i_id is >= 284` then append `cnint <=65` to the query after the `and` else append the other one. This query is in a stored procedure.

```
Select cnint as Id, cnabbv as Code, rtrim(cnname) as Name, i_id as CId, cntry as CCode 
from money.country where cntype = 1 and (CASE 
                                             WHEN i_id = 284 THEN cnint <= 65
                                             ELSE cnint > 65 
                                         END)
order by cnname;
```

This query is in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't supported there. Try this:

```
Select cnint as Id, cnabbv as Code, rtrim(cnname) as Name, i_id as CId, cntry as CCode 
from money.country where cntype = 1 and
((i_id = 284 AND cnint <= 65) OR (coalesce(i_id, 0) != 284 and cnint > 65))
order by cnname;
```

Comment: this returns restults with `cnint <= 65` and `cnint > 65`

Comment: I fixed it: `((i_id = 284 AND cnint <= 65) OR (i_id <> 284 AND cnint > 65))`

Comment: Yes, will edit to reflect that. Your solution still isn't quite right if I_id is nullable.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with out the `case` like this

```
select cnint as Id, 
       cnabbv as Code, 
       rtrim(cnname) as Name, 
       i_id as CId, 
       cntry as CCode 
from money.country 
where cntype = 1 and ( ( i_id = 284 AND cnint <= 65 ) OR (coalesce(i_id, 0) != 284 and cnint>65) )
order by cnname;
```

As `case` returns scalar value, you can do the same using `case` like this
but it is more readable with out the `case`

```
   select cnint as Id, 
           cnabbv as Code, 
           rtrim(cnname) as Name, 
           i_id as CId, 
           cntry as CCode 
    from money.country 
    where cntype = 1  AND 1 = (CASE WHEN (i_id = 284 AND cnint <= 65 ) OR (coalesce(i_id, 0) != 284 and cnint >65)  
                                    THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0 
                               END)
order by cnname;
```

Comment: this returns restults with `cnint <= 65` and `cnint > 65`